# reflection for orika customMap of different fieldNames

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping, webservice-client, orika

Suppose we have 2 DTOs:

```
public class ClassA {
    private String elementAClassA;
    private String elementBClassA;
    private Integer elementCClassA;
}

public class ClassB {
    private String elementAClassB;
    private String elementBClassB;
    private Integer elementCClassB;
}
```

How to map these DTOs using generic code (or reflection/customised), ie without simply using:

```
MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
        mapperFactory.classMap(ClassA.class, ClassB.class)
                .field("elementAClassA", "elementAClassB")
                .field("elementBClassA", "elementBClassB")
                .field("elementCClassA", "elementCClassB").register();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I found the solution and hope will help others.
Steps are as below:

1. Overide newClassMapBuilder of Factory class.
2. fetch fields of both classes using Field reflection. 
3. map new field to build, if elementName matched.
4. Then, create factory and pass this overiden class.

-- Point 1-3 are in below code: 
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import ma.glasnost.orika.DefaultFieldMapper;
import ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFactory;
import ma.glasnost.orika.metadata.ClassMapBuilder;
import ma.glasnost.orika.metadata.ClassMapBuilder.Factory;
import ma.glasnost.orika.metadata.Type;
import ma.glasnost.orika.property.PropertyResolverStrategy;

public class PlainElementToStdElementMapper extends Factory {

    @Override
    protected <A, B> ClassMapBuilder<A, B> newClassMapBuilder(
            Type<A> aType, Type<B> bType,
            MapperFactory mapperFactory,
            PropertyResolverStrategy propertyResolver,
            DefaultFieldMapper[] defaults) {
        final ClassMapBuilder<A, B> newBuilder = super.newClassMapBuilder(
                aType, bType, mapperFactory, propertyResolver, defaults);

        Field[] sourceFields = aType.getRawType().getDeclaredFields();
        Field[] destFields = bType.getRawType().getDeclaredFields();

        for (int elementA = 0; elementA < sourceFields.length; elementA++) {
            for (int elementB = 0; elementB < destFields.length; elementB++) {
                if (sourceFields[elementA].getName().equalsIgnoreCase( "Std"+destFields[elementB].getName())) {
                    newBuilder.field(sourceFields[elementA].getName(), destFields[elementB].getName());
                }
            }
        }
        return newBuilder;
    }
}


4. Create factory:

        final MapperFactory factory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().
                    classMapBuilderFactory(new PlainElementToStdElementMapper()).build();

         factory.classMap(ClassA.class, ClassB.class).byDefault().register();
                MapperFacade mapperFacade = factory.getMapperFacade();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to map common attributes from one representation (ClassA) to the other (ClassB), you would use the `byDefault()` as shown in the [documentation](https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/mappings-via-classmapbuilder.html).

```
mapperFactory.classMap(BasicPerson.class, BasicPersonDto.class)
    .field("name", "fullName")
    .field("age", "currentAge")
    .byDefault()
    .register();
```

Based on your example it isn't clear if the types are different or the names are different between your two representations (it isn't readable as Java).  Reflection would only be useful if the fields were named the same in which case you should just use `byDefault()`, or maybe if they were the same type and you only had one of each type in each representation you could kind of do an autowired-style mapping; but you would be making all sorts of assumptions you wouldn't want to make.

Comment: byDefault() can be used only when fieldName are same for both class,. irrespective of type. btw, I found the solution. It is possible by overiding newClassMapBuilder method of factory.. I will post the solution soon below. :)

Comment: I realize that, but (prior to your update) it wasn't possible to tell if you were giving names or types.